# Laravel Logging in user

Tags: php, laravel-5, login-script

I am a bit of a newbie to Laravel and I have setup a table User with fields username and password.

My sign in screen has a form  with these fields duly declared and I have a function is UserController:

```
public function SignIn(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,
        [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

    if (Auth::attempt([ 'username' => $request['username'], 'password' =>$request['password'] ]) )
    {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

I know it is getting there OK because I can see the error messages if I submit the form blank.

I have removed the default User Auth.

When I submit I get:

> ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 114: Argument 1 passed
>   to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be
>   an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
>   App\User given, called in
>   /home/sites/mysticsisterfilms.com/public_html/admin/protected/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php
>   on line 378 and defined

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I realised that I had messed up an definition who I have amended it to  class User extends Model implements Authenticatable. However even though the username and password are definitely correct it is not authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer which I hope will be useful. In my database I had put the password in "as it were", ie mypassword.

Laravel assumes it is encrypted so of course it was always returning no match